# Waybar: why is the bottom bar not eluding windows?

Tags: kde, wayland, plasma, layout

I am on Ubuntu 23.10, x64 machine, everything up to date and using Wayland.

I am enjoying waybar a lot and playing with configuration I managed to obtain two different bars, one on the top and one on the bottom.

Problem is: the top one eludes windows (i.e. maximizing a window does not cover it) while the bottom one does not (i.e. maximizing a window covers it completely).

My waybar config is the following:

```
[
  {
    // Basic infos
    "name": "header",
    "layer": "top",
    // Disposition
    "modules-left": [
      "custom/launcher",
      "cpu",
      "memory",
      "custom/media",
      "network"
    ],
    "modules-center": [
      "tray"
    ],
    "modules-right": [
      "backlight",
      "pulseaudio",
      "clock",
      "battery"
    ],
    // Built-in modules
    "pulseaudio": {
      "tooltip": false,
      "scroll-step": 5,
      "format": "{icon} {volume}%",
      "format-muted": "{icon} {volume}%",
      "format-icons": {
        "default": [
          "",
          "",
          ""
        ]
      }
    },
    "network": {
      "tooltip": false,
      "format-wifi": "  {essid}",
      "format-ethernet": "",
      "on-click": "/usr/bin/systemsettings kcm_networkmanagement"
    },
    "backlight": {
      "tooltip": false,
      "format": " {}%",
      "interval": 1,
      "on-scroll-up": "light -A 5",
      "on-scroll-down": "light -U 5"
    },
    "battery": {
      "states": {
        "good": 95,
        "warning": 30,
        "critical": 20
      },
      "format": "{icon}  {capacity}%",
      "format-charging": " {capacity}%",
      "format-plugged": " {capacity}%",
      "format-alt": "{time} {icon}",
      "format-icons": [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    },
    "tray": {
      "icon-size": 21,
      "spacing": 10
    },
    "clock": {
      "format": "{: %I:%M %p  %d/%m/%Y}",
      "on-click": "/usr/bin/plasmawindowed org.kde.plasma.calendar"
    },
    "cpu": {
      "interval": 2,
      "format": " {}%",
      "max-length": 10,
      "on-click": "konsole -e btop"
    },
    "memory": {
      "interval": 2,
      "format": " {}%",
      "max-length": 10,
      "on-click": "konsole -e btop"
    },
    // Custom modules (some of them courtesy of River WM + modifications)
    "custom/launcher": {
      "format": " ",
      "on-click": "albert show",
      "on-click-right": "rofi -show drun"
    },
  },
  {
    // Basic infos
    "name": "footer",
    "position": "bottom",
    "height": 32,
    "margin-right": 10,
    "margin-bottom": 10,
    // Disposition
    "modules-left": [
      "custom/tuitext",
      "custom/tuipt",
      "custom/stui",
      "custom/gpgtui",
      "custom/dockertui",
      "custom/gitui",
      "custom/bandtui"
    ],
    "modules-center": [],
    "modules-right": [
      "disk",
      "bluetooth"
    ],
    // Custom modules
    "custom/bandtui": {
      "format": "",
      "on-click": "konsole -e 'sudo bandwhich'"
    },
    "custom/gitui": {
      "format": "",
      "on-click": "konsole -e lazygit"
    },
    "custom/dockertui": {
      "format": "",
      "on-click": "konsole -e lazydocker"
    },
    "custom/gpgtui": {
      "format": "",
      "on-click": "konsole -e gpg-tui"
    },
    "custom/stui": {
      "format": "",
      "on-click": "konsole -e s-tui"
    },
    "custom/tuipt": {
      "format": "",
      "on-click": "konsole -e tptable"
    },
    "custom/tuitext": {
      "format": "",
      "on-click": "konsole -e lvim"
    },
    // Integrated modules
    "bluetooth": {
      "on-click": "plasma-open-settings kcm_bluetooth"
    },
    "disk": {
      "format": "{path}   {percentage_used}%",
      "on-click": "pcmanfm-qt"
    }
    // Modules below this line are not yet added and should be considered WIP
  }
]
```

What am I missing? I also tried adding "exclusive" and "layer" options, without any result

I tried googling and editing that file with both "exclusive" and "layer". I would like the bottom bar to be also able to elude windows.